# Payum - Dispatched event on capture?

Tags: symfony, events, payum

I'd like to know if Payum (or PayumBundle) dispatch an event when the payment is captured?
The aim is to send a confirmation email to the customer.

I found nothing is the doc, and I found only three events in the code source :

- payum.gateway.pre_execute
- payum.gateway.execute
- payum.gateway.post_execute

But I guess it has no connection with the payment itself. Btw, it seems never dispatched with a Stripe payment.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Payum does not dispatch any events by default. It is designed to be extended by an extension. For example if you want to do some stuff on an instance push notification (Paypal IPN) you can add an extension like one described here: http://payum.org/doc/1.0/Core/instant-payment-notification

There is also an extension which [dispatch events](https://github.com/Payum/Payum/blob/master/src/Payum/Core/Bridge/Symfony/Extension/EventDispatcherExtension.php). You have to manually create it and add to payum.

Answer (score 0):

I encounter the same issue : **dispatching a custom event on some payment actions**. In my case I want to deal with *Authorize* and *Capture* actions.

I noticed that **Payum requests may be processed many times for 1 payment action**, that's why I need to mark my payment as processed in order to dispatch only once my custom event (purpose of `Payment::$customPaymentEventDispatched` property).

Here is my Payment entity :

```
<?php

namespace MyApp\PaymentBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Payum\Core\Model\Payment as BasePayment;

class Payment extends BasePayment
{
    // ...

    // Not persisted
    protected $payable;
    protected $customPaymentEventDispatched = false;

    // ...

    public function setPayable($payable)
    {
        $this->payable = $payable;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getPayable()
    {
        return $this->payable;
    }

    public function markAsCustomPaymentEventDispatched()
    {
        $this->customPaymentEventDispatched = true;

        return $this;
    }

    public function isCustomPaymentEventDispatched()
    {
        return $this->customPaymentEventDispatched;
    }
}
```

Then register the Payum eventDispatcherExtension and my custom listener

```
services:        

    payum.extension.event_dispatcher:
        class: Payum\Core\Bridge\Symfony\Extension\EventDispatcherExtension
        arguments: ["@event_dispatcher"]
        tags:
            - { name: payum.extension, all: true, prepend: false }

    my_app_payment.payum.listener.payment_listener:
        class: MyApp\PaymentBundle\EventListener\PaymentListener
        arguments:
            - "@monolog.logger.payment"
        tags:
            - { name: kernel.event_listener, event: payum.gateway.post_execute }
```

And the code of the listener :

```
<?php

namespace MyApp\PaymentBundle\EventListener;

use Payum\Core\Bridge\Symfony\Event\ExecuteEvent;
use Payum\Core\Request\Authorize;
use Payum\Core\Request\BaseGetStatus;
use Payum\Core\Request\Capture;
use Payum\Core\Model\PaymentInterface;
use Payum\Core\Request\GetHumanStatus;
use Psr\Log\LoggerInterface;
use Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventDispatcherInterface;
use MyApp\PaymentBundle\Entity\Payment;
use MyApp\PaymentBundle\Event\PayablePaymentStatusChangeEvent;
use MyApp\PaymentBundle\PaymentEvents;

class PaymentListener
{
    protected $logger;

    public function __construct(LoggerInterface $logger)
    {
        $this->logger = $logger;
    }

    public function onPayumGatewayPostexecute(ExecuteEvent $event, $eventName, EventDispatcherInterface $eventDispatcher)
    {
        $request = $event->getContext()->getRequest();

        // Exclude Payum GetStatus request
        // => protect from infinite loop as following code execute one GetStatus request
        if ($request instanceof BaseGetStatus) {
            return;
        }
        // Request types requiring dispatching an event
        if (!($request instanceof Authorize || $request instanceof Capture)) {
            return;
        }

        $payment = $request->getFirstModel();
        if (!$payment instanceof PaymentInterface) {
            return;
        }

        $event->getContext()->getGateway()->execute($status = new GetHumanStatus($payment));

        if (!$payment->isCustomPaymentEventDispatched()) {
            if ($request instanceof Capture && $status->isCaptured())
            {
                $payable = $payment->getPayable();

                $this->logger->info('Dispatching PAYMENT_SUCCESS for '.$payable->__toString());

                $tmEvent = new PayablePaymentStatusChangeEvent($payment->getPayable());
                $eventDispatcher->dispatch(PaymentEvents::PAYMENT_PENDING, $tmEvent);

                $payment->markAsCustomPaymentEventDispatched();
            }
            elseif ($request instanceof Authorize && $status->isAuthorized())
            {
                $payable = $payment->getPayable();

                $this->logger->info('Dispatching PAYMENT_PENDING for '.$payable->__toString());

                $tmEvent = new PayablePaymentStatusChangeEvent($payment->getPayable());
                $eventDispatcher->dispatch(PaymentEvents::PAYMENT_PENDING, $tmEvent);

                $payment->markAsCustomPaymentEventDispatched();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I'm not fully satisfied of this implementation but I did not find out a better way to achieve that. I'll appreciate any feedback about this !

Answer (score 0):

That's how you can check whether payment is captured or not:

```
use Payum\Core\Action\CapturePaymentAction;
use Payum\Core\Bridge\Symfony\Event\ExecuteEvent;
use Payum\Core\Request\Capture;
use Payum\Core\Request\GetHumanStatus;

class SuccessPaymentListener
{
    public function onPostExecute(ExecuteEvent $event) {
        $context = $event->getContext();
        $action = $context->getAction();
        $request = $context->getRequest();
        if ($action instanceof CapturePaymentAction && $request instanceof Capture) {
            $status = new GetHumanStatus($request->getToken());
            $gateway = $context->getGateway();
            $gateway->execute($status);
            if ($status->isCaptured()) {
                $payment = $status->getFirstModel();
                //here is your stuff
            }
        }
    }
}
```

services.yml:

```
app.payum.extension.event_dispatcher:
    class: Payum\Core\Bridge\Symfony\Extension\EventDispatcherExtension
    arguments: ["@event_dispatcher"]
    tags:
        - { name: payum.extension, all: true, prepend: false }

app.success_payment_listener:
    class: AppBundle\Listener\SuccessPaymentListener
    tags:
        - { name: kernel.event_listener, event: payum.gateway.post_execute, method: onPostExecute }
```